# How to change self.driver.get() to only self.get() in class?

Tags: python, selenium, class

I've been looking for an answer but cant find one

Let's say I have this,

```
self.driver =  webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
```

and then I use,

```
self.driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
```

Is there a way for me to use just 'self.' on the next method where everything from self.driver pops up? Like so,

```
self.get('http://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `get`-method for your class that calls `driver.get`. Then you can refer to it inside the class as `self.get`.

```
class CustomDriver:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

    def another_method(self):
        self.get("<some_url>")
        # do some other stuff here...

# initiate driver first
driver = ...

drv = CustomDriver(driver)
drv.get("<some_url>")
```

Answer (score 0):

### [`self` in Python class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/)

> self represents the instance of the class. By using the ***self*** keyword
> we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python. It
> binds the attributes with the given arguments.

In short, ***self*** is always pointing to current object.

But `get()` is method from the [WebDriver implementation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver). So to access `get()` you have to invoke it through the instance of the WebDriver i.e. ***driver*** which you have already initialized through:

```
self.driver =  webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
```